# Using Matlab libraries in C++ (Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, matlab

I want to call Matlab functions from within C++. Is there any Matlab library available to use under linux? If so, where can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you have matlab installed.

Here is a good tutorial describing how to use matlab libraries from C. http://linux4research.blogspot.kr/2007/10/calling-matlab-functions-from-c.html

Do you have a matlab account ? You can find more information here http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/compiler/f2-998954.html#bqlsafn-33_1